# comparar dois objetos em java

Tags: java

boa noite. estou trabalhando com um arraylist, e precisava garantir que não sejam inseridos objetos repetidos. O meu objeto possui uma matriz[5][5] que é o principal elemento que preciso garantir que não seja repetido. alguem teria alguma sugestão?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar uma `TreeSet`?

Comment: Então, é que fiz o programa todo em arraylist. Talvez vc saberia como passar de treeset para arraylist, ai era só mudar essa parte de inserção.

Comment: Precisaria entender como está funcionando o seu código para ver se é possível ou não utilizar uma `TreeSet`, mas se não pode repetir elementos, geralmente o `Set` é bem mais adequado.

Comment: Por favor mostre como está seu código. Não está claro o que você está tentando fazer: você tem um `ArrayList` com elementos na forma `matriz[5][5]`? Qual o tipo dessa matriz? É ela inteira que não pode se repetir? Ou seus dados estão representados de outro jeito? O `Set` (`TreeSet`, `HashSet`) é a maneira natural de se criar conjuntos (i.e. coleções onde os elementos não se repetem), você não precisa fazer mais nada além de adicioná-los, então não faz sentido "passar de treeset para arraylist". Mostre o seu código e provavelmente poderemos te ajudar melhor.

Comment: É uma matriz[5][5] inteira, com o TreeSet vai funcionar. Mas no metodo compareTo, vou ter que comparar elemento por elemento dessa matriz?

Comment: @jakson Edite sua pergunta colocando o código que você tem até agora, vai ajudar bastante... Quanto a comparar, não sei se o `TreeSet` é a solução mais adequada, talvez o `HashSet` seja melhor. Se seus elementos podem ser ordenados, o `TreeSet` é melhor (aí você vai usar o `compareTo` ou um `Comparator`), caso contrário o `HashSet` é melhor (aí você vai usar o `hashCode`). E pra garantir que dois elementos não sejam repetidos, você tem que compará-los por completo, não?

Comment: blz, vou usar o treeSet aqui se não der certo posto o código.valeu

Comment: onde que entra `comparar dois objetos em java` na sua pergunta? arrume o titulo, poste seu código e explique melhor oq quer fazer

Comment: `public class BingoSorte {`
    `private String nome;`
    `private int identificador = 0;`
    `private int cartela[][] = new int[5][5];`
     `private int cont;}`              Essa é minha entidade com seus atributos. Essa Cartela[][] é preenchida com números inteiros. Utiizando um TreeSet<BingoSorte> para armazenar objetos do tipo acima.A pergunta é. Como devo implementar  o corpo do meu compareTo para que na hora de inserir objetos, ele compare para que não insira repetidos.No caso como comparar as cartelas[][] de cada objeto.

Comment: Vc possui uma classe Cartela? O atributo cartela da sua classe BingoSorte serve pra quê? Por favor, adicione os detalhes da pergunta na pergunta e não nos comentários

Answer (score 2):

Não está claro onde você está querendo chegar, mas vou tentar responder com o que entendi até agora:

Se você não pode ter elementos repetidos, um `Set` (conjunto) é a estrutura de dados mais adequada. Resta saber **qual** conjunto é melhor pra você.

Se seus elementos podem ser colocados em uma ordem total, então o `TreeSet` é o mais adequado: não só ele garante a unicidade, mas também mantém seus elementos em ordem:

```
Comparator<int[][]> c = new Comparator<int[][]>() {
    public int compare(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        ...
    }
};
TreeSet<int[][]> c = new TreeSet<int[][]>(c);
```

Caso contrário, um `HashSet` é mais adequado. Entretanto, a comparação de arrays em Java é feita por referência, não por valor. Se você quer que **o conteúdo** dos arrays sejam comparados, é necessário usar um objeto *wrapper* que faça uso de [`deepEquals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) e [`deepHashCode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
class MeuObjeto {
    private int[][] array;

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( o instanceof MeuObjeto )
            return Arrays.deepEquals(this.array, ((MeuObjeto)o).array);
        else
            return false;
    }

    pubilc int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(array);
    }
}
HashSet<MeuObjeto> c = new HashSet<MeuObjeto>();
```

Por fim, se você quer usar o `HashSet` mas gostaria que os elementos fossem retornados na mesma ordem em que foram inseridos, você pode usar `LinkedHashSet` no lugar dele. O exemplo é idêntico ao item anterior, só muda a classe.

[Artigo para referência](http://www.devmedia.com.br/diferencas-entre-treeset-hashset-e-linkedhashset-em-java/29077).